# Google Annotationchart - Rebase index=100 upon Rangechange

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have an Google Annotation Chart to show relative performance of different investments. User should be able compare performance over a selected time frame, that is, the series values should be rebased / indexed to 100 at the startdate of the visible range of the chart once the timeframe is changed.

Other packages like Amcharts offer a "comparable" function, so have been looking for options like "scaleColumns" and "scaleType" in Google Docs and in other questions here, not finding any clue on how to do this.

Is there any feature I can use and might have missed, or what would be the best approach to recalculate the DataTable with index=100 upon "rangechange".

Code and screenshot is below:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'line', 'table','annotationchart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// ---------- Chart ---------------------------- //
function drawChart() {
  //data query
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gw67zHpKyEd1nu_V698yqYqNgE0x21_ZE_QDHJmsgtE/gviz/tq?gid=803335131&headers=1&range=A1:n451');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}
function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }
  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var options = {
    title: 'Development of the choosen Portfolio since 2008',
    legend: {
      textStyle : { fontSize: 8 },
      maxLines : 2,
      position: 'top'
    },
    width: '30%',
    height: 700,
    lineWidth: 1,
    hAxis: {
      format: 'M/d/yy',
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      scaleType: 'log',
      title: 'Return (log scale)'
    },
    //theme: 'maximized',
    chartArea:{
      left:0,
      top:20,
      width:'30%',
      height:'85%'
    },
    series: {
      22: {
        lineWidth: 3,
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'))
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'rangechange', rangechange_handler);

function rangechange_handler(e) {
  console.log('You changed the range to ', e['start'], ' and ', e['end']);
  // How to recalculate datatable to keep index=100 for all series upon rangechange?
}
```

[image: Rebase Index Picture]

**Update:**

There is a way, working on it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-visualization-api/compare$20zoom|sort:relevance/google-visualization-api/8HjybllsufY/z5uak6AymLcJ

Comment: could you please clarify _series should be rebased to 100 in the visible range_? not following, do you always want 100 records in the visible range?

Comment: For clarification, the series values should be rebased / indexed to 100 at the startdate of the visible range of the chart. So once visible timeframe is changed the first visible value of all series should be recalculated to an index value of 100.

Comment: I believe the "rebase" operation is effectively changing the values of all series such that all the series start at, say, 100 on the first visible timeframe of the chart.  That way you can compare how all of the series change relative to each other thereafter.  There is not an option to do this in the Google AnnotationChart.  You could change the values yourself, after each update of the range slider.  But that would be more expensive than desired.  Plus, you probably want to show both the original values and the rebased values.

Answer (score 0):

After an extended period of pain got it working, hope it helps somebody: https://jsfiddle.net/AlexHorn/a9z15syr/

```
var viewColumns = [0];
var colors = [];
for (var i = 0; i < columnIndices.length; i++) {
  viewColumns.push({
    label: data.getColumnLabel(columnIndices[i]),
    type: 'number',
    calc: (function(x) {
      // use a closure here to lock the value of i to each column
      return function(dt, row) {
        // return the value normalized to the first row in the view
        return dt.getValue(row, columnIndices[x]) / dt.getValue(0, columnIndices[x]);
      };
    })(i)
  });
}
```